# Recursive function in PHP inside a while

Tags: php, recursion, while-loop

I'm doing the Pandemic Board Game. I'm making the game logic in PHP (most of it) , and when there's a city with more than 3 cubes in it, it happens an outbreak which is that th cities connected to that one will increase 1 cube.

Now, I'm doing all this in PHP, and I have a function that increases the cubes in a city and, for every city connected to it, with an outbreak, increases as well, so I'm doing a recursive function inside a while.

(I'm telling you all this because I'm gonna cut some code in the example. Hope I made myself clear)

**PHP function**

```
  function AddInfectionCubes($city_name, $n_cubes, $game_id) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO game_city(id_game, city_name, disease_cubes) VALUES('$game_id', '$city_name', '$n_cubes')";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $insert);
    if(!$res) {
      $sql_cubes = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT disease_cubes FROM game_city WHERE city_name='$city_name' AND id_game='$game_id'");
      $get_cubes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_cubes);

      $disease_cubes = $get_cubes['disease_cubes'] + $n_cubes;//quantidade de cubos após adicionar outros aos que já existiam
      if ($disease_cubes > 3){
        $update_outbreak_marker = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Game SET outbreak_marker = outbreak_marker + 1 WHERE id = '$game_id'");

        $outbreak_cities = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT city_to FROM connections WHERE city_from = '$city_name'");
        while ($c = mysqli_fetch_assoc($outbreak_cities)){
          $city_to = $c['city_to'];
          $n_cubes = 1;
          AddInfectionCubes($city_to, $n_cubes, $game_id);
        }
      } else {
        $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE game_city SET disease_cubes='$disease_cubes' WHERE city_name='$city_name' AND id_game='$game_id'");
      }
    }
  };

  AddInfectionCubes($city_name, $n_cubes, $game_id);
```

I don't what I'm doing wrong, but the recursive function doesn't work. Is it because it's inside a while?

**NOTE**

If I don't make this a recursive function, it works perfect (but doens't do the outbreak thing). The sql is good, the variables are good, etc.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way I cand o this without the recursive function? Can I do it with a while?

Comment: Where is `$disease_cubes` defined?

Comment: Where is `$outbreak_cities` defined?

Comment: in the comments.. , i told i was going to simplify the code

Comment: Simplify it so we have as much as the picture we need to see potential issue. I think those variables might be important. There is a fine balance that needs to be met.

Comment: @Script47 I'm gonna put all the code then, sorry

Comment: @Script47 you have any idea?